# How to change the title of active terminal after SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, window-title

I can change the title of terminal using the following command:

```
echo -en '\033]0;20.11\a'
```

But if I use it after `ssh` command it won't work:

```
ssh user@192.168.20.11;echo -en '\033]0;20.11\a'
```

In this case, the title is changed only after I sign out of `192.168.20.11`. Is there any way to change the title after `ssh`?

Comment: `cmd1; cmd2` runs the commands in order, waiting for the first to finish before running the second. Why not set the title first and then run ssh?

Comment: @ilkkachu You are right. I feel like a fool now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
ssh -t user@192.168.20.11 "echo -en '\033]0;20.11\a';bash"
```

Comment: it seems it changes it just for a second and changes back immediatelly

Comment: @FantomX1 Probably your remote bash init scripts have the same command already, changing it to something else. In this case, you need to tweak the bash startups scripts (`.bashrc`, `bash_profile`, ...).